# react-navigation - drawer navigation inside stack navigation in react native

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation

[Image of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeQvc.jpg), [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTZw2.png)

Managed to build my first React native-navigation v2, a stack navigation from LoginScreen to HomeScreen.

The problem I have is that I tried putting a Drawer Navigation on the HomeScreen and placing it inside the stack navigation but I can't understand the way to do it.

> **error message:** Unable to resolve ./src/components/HomeScreen" from ".//src/components/DrawerNavigator.js`: The module`./src/components/HomeScreen` could not be found"
>   Failed building JavaScript bundle

Take a look at my code below.

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {

  render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
      barStyle="dark-content"
      />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerNavigator')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Header, List, ListItem, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Login from './src/components/Login/Login';
import LoginForm from './src/components/Login/LoginForm';
import HomeScreen from './src/components/HomeScreen';
import DayPlanScreen from './src/components/DayPlanScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerNavigator from './src/components/DrawerNavigator'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
{

        <AppStackNavigator />
}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: Login,
  Home: HomeScreen,
  DrawerNavigator: DrawerNavigator
})


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  addBtn: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 0
  },
});
```

**DrawerNavigator.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import HomeScreen from './src/components/HomeScreen';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  DayPlan: DayPlanScreen
})

export default DrawerNavigator;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:  1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

**HomeScreen**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>HomeScreen</Text>
        <Button
        title='LOGIN SCREEN'
        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        fontWeight='700'
        backgroundColor='#3AD7FF'
        color='#424242'
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#424242'
  }
});
```

Comment: You named it `AppDrawerNavigator` but importing it as `DrawerNavigator`

Comment: Okay! :) Now its imported and exported only as DrawerNavigator, as seen. Seems like a step closer but the error message changed now to: Unable to resolve ./src/components/HomeScreen" from ".//src/components/DrawerNavigator.js`: The module `./src/components/HomeScreen` could not be found"
Failed building JavaScript bundle

Comment: And HomeScreen should also be named correctly, when imported to DrawerNavigator.

Comment: Did you fix the problem? Whenever the error says `could not be found ` it usually means you made a typo somewhere or did not properly import/export, as well as your folder structure

Comment: It still remains:  Unable to resolve ./src/components/HomeScreen" from ".//src/components/DrawerNavigator.js. Added picture of the code in the question above there are the related components and the nav goes from loginForm to DrawerNavigator.

Comment: Are all your components in the same directory? Also, does your terminal give you more information about the error?

Comment: Damn this was tricky, got a slight headache of this problem yesterday. Yes they are in same dir but found out the error in expo app terminal was a bit more detailed, added the image of the red screen also in the post.

Comment: @SGhaleb thanks mate, maybe I might look closer on a solution with this concept of not nesting navs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html